# Android How To Get Bitmap From CameraX and display in ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

i'm using cameraX to capture image and save to gallery, and it's working.

but, how to get that captured image, so I can preview in ImageView

```
private void capturePhoto() {
    long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, timeStamp);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");


    imageCapture.takePicture(
            new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    contentValues
            ).build(),
            getExecutor(),
            new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                    
                    //maybe here the code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(Utama.this,"Error: "+exception.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

}
```

I'm trying to `outputFileResults.getSavedUri()` but still cant get image.

how to get captured image in Bitmap so I can preview in ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this code sample in CameraX test app: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/a7879800fceeabe7e53b67bbd882db7f852706e3/camera/integration-tests/viewtestapp/src/main/java/androidx/camera/integration/view/TransformFragment.java#L380